# I can't connect to OSSIM server

Tags: authentication, siem, vmware

I installed OSSIM in VMware workstation.The installation was successful.But when I entered the login and the password I have this message " incorrect login" I know that la login must be "root".

[image]
Please how can I fix this problem.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: You might be better off posting this on ServerFault.  This does not have to do with IS.

Comment: This is a question for their support docs. I have found multiple sources online that can provide the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have been given a temporary root password right after you setup the server.  See page 28 of [AlienVaultUSM Setup Guide](https://www.alienvault.com/doc-repo/usm/setup-and-configuration/AlienVault-USM-4.8-5.x-Initial-Setup-Guide.pdf) for further details.